# I need a simple way to format the date from SQL using Perl

Tags: perl

I have the following date format from SQL Server: 2014-04-14 11:36:34.000

I need to strip the time and format it as: 4/14/2014

What's the simplest way to achieve this?

I'm assuming some variation of DateTime::Format::Strptime.

This is what im trying to get working...

Thanks

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $PictureDate = "2014-04-14 11:36:34.000";
my $dateparse = $parser->parse_datetime($PictureDate);
my $ShortDateTime = $dateparse->strftime("%m/%d/%Y");

print "$ShortDateTime\n";
```

Comment: What happens when you run this? What is the output? What is wrong with it? How did you configure the `$parser` instance of `DateTime::Format::Strptime`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing missing here is the initialization of the `$parser` variable.

This should do it:

```
my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%Y-%m-%d',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $PictureDate = "2014-04-14 11:36:34.000";
$PictureDate =~ /^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/;
printf("%d\/%d\/%d\n", $2, $3, $1);
```